# If $\frac{AB}{A'B'}=\frac{AC}{A'C'}=\frac{BC}{B'C'}$ then prove that $\triangle{ABC}$ is similar to $\triangle{A'B'C'}$

Tags: geometry, triangles

> If $\frac{AB}{A'B'}=\frac{AC}{A'C'}=\frac{BC}{B'C'}$ then prove that $\triangle{ABC}$ is similar to $\triangle{A'B'C'}$

How to prove that angles are equal? I don't really know where to start

Edit : solution shouldn't use trigonometry.

Edit : Similarity definition: when corresponding angles of two shapes are equal and corresponding sides are proportional.

Comment: What's your  similarity definition.?

Comment: @MyGlasses common high-school definition of similarity as described [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_(geometry))

Comment: @GLASSIC The common definition of similarity of triangles in my high-school was "the sides are directly proportional" and the fact that this was equivalent to having the same angles was a theorem known as "third similarity criterion".

Comment: @G-Sassatelli post edited and a definition for similarity is added.

Comment: Also known as "first similarity criterion".

Comment: One can use extended sine rule

Comment: @N.S.JOHN It might not be the case, but invoking the function $\sin \theta$ to prove one of the elementary facts which put together the angles of a triangle and the ratios of their sides is very likely to produce hidden circular arguments. Not very wise, IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prove that the three angles are orderly congruent:

Consider the triangle $\triangle ABC$ and the *half*-lines $Ab:=\overrightarrow{AB},\,Ac:=\overrightarrow{AC}$ which border the angle $\angle BAC$. There is exactly one point $B''\in Ab$ such that $A'B'\cong AB''$ and exactly one point $C''\in Ac$ such that $A'C'=AC''$.

By the inverse of Thales' intercept theorem, $B''C''\parallel BC$. Hence, $\angle C''B''A\cong \angle CBA$ and $\angle B''C''A\cong \angle BCA$ by parallel theorem.

By Thales' intercept theorem, $BC:B''C''=AB:AB''$ and, since $AB''\cong A'B'$, this implies that $B''C''\cong B'C'$.

Ny the third congruence theorem (SSS), $\triangle AB''C''\cong \triangle A'B'C'$ and, hence, $\angle BAC\cong\angle B'A'C'$, $\angle ABC\cong \angle AB''C''\cong A'B'C'$ and $\angle ACB\cong\angle AC''B''\cong \angle A'C'B'$.

Q.E.D.

Comment: Add a figure if it's possible.

Comment: @MyGlasses I wouldn't lie if I said that I have no access to Geogebra right now, but the actual reason why I didn't do it in the first place is that I'm lazy.